# wordpress 4.4 self hosted video (html5) doesn't show

Tags: php, shortcode, videos, html5

I was developing WP theme on my localhost (version 4.3). The client wanted to be able to add self-hosted videos. So I wrote shortcode and implemented it in Visual Composer. Basically, this shortcode returns standart markup:

```
<video>
 //<source for mp4>
 //<source for webm>
 //<source for ogv>
</video>
```

This worked fine until client updated his WP to 4.4 version. Now video just doesn't show up. While inspecting the html there are no "not found" errors, shortcode returns correct path to video (for example .mp4):

[image]

While inspecting "Sources" section there are no "Media" block in it:

[image]

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Did the client change anything else like server version?

Comment: Show your markup please.